# Change Text of <summary> Element On Click

Tags: jquery

I would like to select a `<details>` element and click an item in the dropdown. After I click the item in the dropdown, I would like the text value of this item to replace the text in the `<summary>` element.

So, the `<summary>` loads with the page and displays "Select Topic". Then, a user clicks on the arrow and selects "1". After clicking, the `<summary>` displays "1" instead of "Select Topic". Here is a JSFiddle of the code so far, but I'm stuck on getting the text to replace the original `<summary>` text:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3mh4cdvf/5/

HTML:

```
<details id="tesing2"><summary>Select Topic</summary>
<div class=div-class style="cursor: pointer;">1</div>
<div class=div-class style="cursor: pointer;">2</div>
</details>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.div-class').click(function (event) {
setTimeout(function() {
var topic = event.target.innerText;
$(summary).innerHTML = topic;
}, 20);
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which of the two answers do you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.text()` to set the text of summary element. Also if there are mutliple such elements you can give some id or class to differentiate them.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('.div-class').click(function(event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var topic = event.target.innerText;
    $("summary").text(topic); //use .text to set value or html
  }, 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details id="tesing2">
  <summary>Select Topic</summary>
  <div class="div-class" style="cursor: pointer;">1</div>
  <div class="div-class" style="cursor: pointer;">2</div>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `$(summary).innerHTML = topic;` is the problem, your selector is not in qoutes and also you use `.html()` to set the html in jQuery.

```js
$('.div-class').click(function (event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var topic = event.target.innerText;
        $('summary').html(topic);
    }, 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details id="tesing2"><summary>Select Topic</summary>
<div class=div-class style="cursor: pointer;">1</div>
<div class=div-class style="cursor: pointer;">2</div>
</details>
```